# Is possible to mask an input in javascript without affect the input value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to apply a mask into a number (Currency format without decimals) but need to be able to show the mask only on user's side (Because the "flat" number is part of a mathematical formula, and can't use the commas or dots on it).

I wanna be able to show something like this on user's side "$253,487" and send this information to the formula "253487".

**This is the last thing that I tried but of course isn't working:**

```js
const number = document.querySelector('.number');

function formatNumber(n) {
  n = String(n).replace(/\D/g, "");
  return n === '' ? n : Number(n).toLocaleString();
}
number.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  const value = element.value;
  element.value = formatNumber(value);

});
```

```html
<input class="number">
```

.

Comment: It seems like the  `formatNumber` is doing all you need: (1) it strips the current input value from punctuation (so that gives you the digit-only number), (2) it adds formatting again - which you want for the display. So you have the logic for both. You speak of "the formula", yet there is no formula in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the ingredients to make it work. Possibly you need to separate your current `formatNumber` function into two functions, so you have one for getting the pure number (digits only), and one for the formatting. Currently that function is doing both.

So like this:

```js
const number = document.querySelector('.number');

function getInputValue(inputElement) {
  return parseInt(inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
}

function formatInputValue(inputElement) {
  let n = getInputValue(inputElement);
  inputElement.value = Number.isNaN(n) ? "$" : "$" + getInputValue(inputElement).toLocaleString();
}

number.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  formatInputValue(e.target);
  // Apply a formula
  let n = getInputValue(e.target);
  console.log("squared=" + (n*n)); // output the square
});
```

```html
<input class="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I almost always use, but modified to your needs. Note that you need to have another hidden input that'll get sent where you keep only the number inside.

```js
const number = document.querySelector('.number_tmp');

function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
  // Strip all characters but numerical ones.
  number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function(n, prec) {
      var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
    };
  // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
  }
  if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
  }
  return "$" + s.join(dec);
}

number.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const element = e.target;
  const value = element.value;
  element.value = number_format(value, 0, '', ',');
  document.getElementById('number').value = value.replace(/\D/g, '')

});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="number_tmp">
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="number">
```